# Facebook login using artdarek/oauth-4 returns blank

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, oauth-2.0

I am attempting to setup facebook login using the artdarek/oauth-4 package. The redirect just returns a blank page with the following url:

```
 https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=web_server&client_id=1423706434575595&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2FcontractorSherpa%2Fpublic%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&scope=email+read_friendlists+user_online_presence
```

I am using Laravel 4.2.4

Route:

```
Route::get('/facebook', 'RegistrationController@loginWithFacebook');
```

RegistrationController:

```
Public function loginWithFacebook() {

    $code = Input::get('code');

    // get fb service
    $fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

    //check for valid code
    // if empty provide user data
        if ( !empty($code)){
            $token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);

            //send a request with it
            $result = json_decode( $fb->request('/me'), true);



        if (!empty($token)) {

            try{
                $user = Sentry::findUserByLogin($result['email']);

                Sentry::login($user, false);

                return Redirect::to('contractors/dashboard');
            }
            catch (Cartalyst\Sentry\Users\UsersNotFoundException $e)
            {
                $user = Sentry::register(array(
                            'activated' => 1,
                            'email' => $result['email'],
                            'password' => $result['password'],
                            'first_name' => $result['firstname'],
                            'last_name' => $result['lastname'],
                    ));
                $group = Sentry::findGroupByName($data['contractor']);
                $user->addGroup($usergroup);

                Sentry::login($user, false);

                return Redirect::to('contractors/dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
    else {
            //get fb authorization
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();

        // return to facebook login url
        return Redirect::to((string)$url);
    }
}
```

In my case, the $code is null, so it the else statement triggers.

I tried dd($url) and got this response:

```
object(OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri)#368 (10) { ["scheme":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(5) "https" ["userInfo":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["rawUserInfo":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["host":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(16) "www.facebook.com" ["port":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> int(443) ["path":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(13) "/dialog/oauth" ["query":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(193) "type=web_server&client_id=1423706434575595&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2FcontractorSherpa%2Fpublic%2Ffacebook&response_type=code&scope=email+read_friendlists+user_online_presence" ["fragment":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> string(0) "" ["explicitPortSpecified":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> bool(false) ["explicitTrailingHostSlash":"OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri":private]=> bool(false) }
```

Though I have added a few lines of code to account for Sentry auth, my code is nearly identical to the the example in the readme file of artdarek package.

How do I get the correct url?

Answer (score 1):

The code above is correct, except that I needed to specifically define a a route in

```
$fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');
```

so that became

```
$fb = OAuth::consumer( 'Facebook', 'http://www.contractorsherpa.com/facebook/' );
```

The page you want to reference in that url is the page you are posting to in your route. Don't forget the trailing slash. the $code will be added after the slash, which then triggers the if statement:

```
if(!empty($code))
```